# Custom font for tabitem in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can i change font inside the tabitem in swiftUI.

I tried `.font(custom())` but that's not changing anything.
I kno how to change font inside the tabview but what i'm looking for is inside the tabitem.

Does anyone know how can i change it?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Try using `.accentColor`